# Is canonical reconsidereing support for android apps on ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

It seems like we are going to have ubuntu touch powered devices in the near time.

Even though I'm willing to have an ubuntu powered device I find it pretty hard for a new competitor in the mobile arena to succeed if it doesn't have lots of apps, and the only way I see this could be achieved in the near feature is supporting android apps. Besides, there are some apps that are clear deal-breaker for many, like whatsapp, facebook, etc.

Jolla seems to think so, and being open source Ubuntu Touch could benefit from all their work supporting android apps.

So I was wondering if Canonical is considering adding support for android apps.

Answer (score 2):

This is what Richard Collins, head of Ubuntu mobile products, has to say on this issue -

> Q. Since Android is also Linux-based, is there any plan for Ubuntu to
>   run Android apps?
>
> A. Many Android developers already use Ubuntu as their desktop OS and
>   we have a very close affinity with them. We intend to encourage them
>   to make their Android applications run on Ubuntu, but we won't
>   engineer any middleware for running Android apps. Developers are
>   intelligent and capable enough to make their apps run on our devices.

You can read his complete interview at [Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2013/01/25/canonical-richard-collins-interview/).

Comment: Yes, I saw that interview (should have added the link myself), I was just asking if they have reconsidered that strategy.