# Android apps on Ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Can Ubuntu Phone run any Android app? And if not so can it be possible in near future in Ubuntu touch? I love the OS but i don't love the apps.

Comment: Many people want to know this. The official answer is, alas, [No](http://askubuntu.com/questions/554495/is-canonical-reconsidereing-support-for-android-apps-on-ubuntu-touch?rq=1).